# I want a set of preset Materials, such as glass, metal, stone, etc

Tags: materials, node-editor, add-on

I would LOVE to have a set of open source preset materials to choose from so that I don't have to figure out all the physics properties for each substance each time I create a material.

For example, I would love to have presets for:
water, gas, glass, metal, stone, clay, fabric, leather, skin, plastic, fire, etc.

Ideally, the physics properties of the presets would be true to life, using the same technical data physicists use.

In the short-term perspective, such accuracy will guarantee the most realistic renderings/simulations.

In the long-term perspective, the accuracy could be of great importance when 3D scanning & printing become more mainstream.

Is there a way to have these presets ready for me whenever I start a new project?

Comment: AFAIK there is no built-in option besides saving a custom startup file, containing all your materials.

Comment: perhaps coding?

Comment: @RBlong2us And [algorithms](https://i.redd.it/ytdyqbyzjkky.png)? Thom, you are probably aware of various lists (like [this ior one](https://pixelandpoly.com/ior.html)) on the internet?